# Use Wolfram curated databases to determine how many randomly chosen people are needed to have a 50% chance two live in the same or adjacent states?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, curated-data, combinatorics, geography

**Background:**

This question is based on one asked on the statistics stack exchange, CrossValidated.SE [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/290980/how-many-americans-randomly-chosen-are-needed-to-have-a-50-chance-two-live-in).  Alas, the full answer to the statistical question seems to require enormous computational resources to perform rigorously, so I gather the only approach forward is to perform instead a stochastic simulation.

Hence this question on Mathematica.SE.

---

**How would one use *Mathematica* and its curated geographic and census database to determine how many Americans, randomly chosen, are needed to have a 50% chance that two of them live in a) the same state or b) in the same or an adjacent state?**

One can determine the populations of each states by:

```
WolframAlpha["US state population table", 
{{"PropertyRanking:USStateData", 1}, "QuantityData"}, 
 PodStates -> {"PropertyRanking:USStateData__More", 
   "PropertyRanking:USStateData__More", 
   "PropertyRanking:USStateData__More"}]
```

One can determine the adjacency matrix of the states (or undirected graph $g$) using GeoData and `neighboring`, as described by this [analogous problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144187/neighboring-counties-within-the-state-of-florida-for-every-county-in-the-state) with the counties of Florida:

```
counties=EntityList[US counties in Florida (administrative divisions)];
```

and

```
Cases[GeoNearest["USCounty", counties[[16]]], Except[counties[[16]]]]
```

(Alas, the generalization to states within the US does not seem to work directly.)

So the approach to part **b)** would be to do a large simulation of choosing $n=2$ people randomly according to the probabilities based on the state populations.  Then find what percentage of the time these two people live in the same or adjacent states.  Surely for $n=2$ this will be a small number, say $1\%$.  Then repeat with $n=3$.  And $n=4$... until one finds the probability of roughly $50\%$.  Is there a more efficient approach?

Given the population statistics in Wolfram curated data and the neighboring state data inherent in the GeoData, what are the numerical values of the solutions to parts **a)** and **b)**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with Mathematica.

Comment: @JimBaldwin:  This question is entirely about *Mathematica*, specifically the methods for using Wolfram's unique curated database of geographic data to compute the adjacency matrix for US states.  I don't know how one would even approach this problem using other computer languages.  (Moreover, I urge you to wait more than two minutes until a question has been fully posted before voting to close it.)

Comment: Pointer : RandomChoice with arguments "list of states" rule "populations of states"

Comment: Excellent pointer, but what's the exact code?

Comment: Not convinced.  The only closely-related product mentioned is WolframAlpha (despite it being called from *Mathematica*) and apparently no work on the problem other than to get data.  Once you have an approach, then how to implement it in *Mathematica* would be just fine.  I didn't see much of any attempt - although after my comment additional information was added.

Comment: I spent three hours programming this problem.  You say "Once you have an approach, ..." well, I outlined exactly one approach.  I'll add a link now to another's problem that describes how to find neighboring regions (in that case counties).  Alas, this code does not easily transfer to states (I've found).

Comment: Sorry, on mobile, so can't type extensively, but I have a good idea for an answer. Let the states be numbered 1to 50 and their populations be in thr list `p`, then `RandomChoice[Range@50 -> p, {10^6, 50}]` will generate a suitable test dataset. Now you just need a test to check how many elements to take until you have 2 adjacent population members.

Comment: You can find a list of which states neighbor which states at http://theincidentaleconomist.com/wordpress/list-of-neighboring-states-with-stata-code/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer is 3.5 when including District of Columbia:

```
states = EntityValue[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], "AdministrativeDivisions"];
pops = AdministrativeDivisionData[states, "Population"][[All, 1]];
(* very slow *)  dists = GeoDistance[{#, #2}][[1]] & @@@ Subsets[states, {2}];
(* fast *)       dists = Uncompress["1:eJztWDkOg0AM3Eh8hP+k4gkUSFSRQn5PAwVKE5G9PONZBBIWje2xx/Z66cfXMK1dCMv+hue8fObH/pEg3uF4vh+pmnGT1Zb41i8lANzWUmWChBpO3JlFmjleNPLlyaad7zPVvyZz/GWUhGwymqfaljC16KgoNCA2K4pa7M55daZR51nacvR76pejU5xP+IkhsfuiuhJPP6cZCJVmopVWxmJNCXNxkdOlnC6zWjPbn1v591JrCXDhkO1EwNBFxIq6AzoWHXH3Awv9AZOLUHCCxPWL1mAmQJiWd904oSME6p3ZbP8btjQYMQ=="];

true = Association[Thread[Join[Pick[Subsets[Range[51], {2}], dists, 0.], Table[{i, i}, {i, 51}]] -> 1]];
N[Mean[Map[Max[Lookup[true, Subsets[Sort[#], {2}], 0]] &,
   RandomChoice[pops -> Range[51], {10000, #}]]]] & /@ {3, 4}
```

> {0.3444, 0.5889}

The `true`-assosation contains the pairs (Michigan, Minnesota) and (New York, Rhode Island), because the first state has an island next to the coast of the other state. The website Jim Baldwin's linked to and using `"BorderingStates"` in Mathematica both disagree on this inclusion. However the populations there are too small to change the result.

Comment: +1, of course the problem is small enough to bruteforce

Comment: Wonderful.  Elegant.  Efficient.  (Somehow, though, your code doesn't work on my v. 10.4.)  Accept.

Comment: +1. A warning to people who attempt to run the code in this answer: the computations might take up to 10-15 minutes.

Comment: @AntonAntonov added altenative for the slow part

Comment: @AntonAntonov you can get a lot of speed up by using ``#[[Range[1, Length[#], 2]]] & @ Normal[GeoDistanceList[spairList] & @ Subsets[states, {2}]]`` instead of that mapped `GeoDistance`. In my experience `GeoDistanceList` is orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 2):

Using the property of "BorderingStates" (assuming this qualifies as adjacent):

```
states = EntityValue[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
   "AdministrativeDivisions"];
pops = AdministrativeDivisionData[states, "Population"][[All, 1]];
f[x_, y_] := If[y == {}, Nothing, x <-> # &
   /@ y]
g = DeleteDuplicates[
   Catenate[
    f[#, EntityValue[#, 
        EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", 
         "BorderingStates"]]] & /@ states], (Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] &)];
grph = Graph[states, g];
sr = Thread[Range[51] -> states];
rnc[n_, num_] := RandomChoice[pops -> Range[51], {n, num}] /. sr;
func[ss_] := Module[{prt = Subsets[ss, {2}]},
  Unitize@
   Total[If[#1 === #2, 1, 
       If[Length[FindPath[grph, ##, {1}]] > 0, 1, 0]] & @@@ prt]]
res[n_, num_] := Total[func /@ rnc[n, num]]/n // N
```

So simulation:

```
TableForm[
 Catenate[Table[{i, j, 
    res[i, j]}, {i, {100, 1000, 10000, 100000}}, {j, {2, 3, 4}}]], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"N", "choice size", "proportion adjacent"}}]
```

[image]